# How to add item depending on number of clicks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, onclick

I have few task in other files, which I am injecting into this file, after that I created `showButton function` which simply change the `state`, and then I have `showButtonNow function`, which display one button and task, which I clicked on. Let's say I click on Eat Dinner it will display me Eat Dinner and than one edit button

When I click one time it work fine, lets say my task is Eat Dinner, it will display me the Eat Dinner and than it will display me the Edit button. My problem is when I click on second time it should display me again one more Eat Dinner and one more Edit button, it does not do it.

Then I added the `console.log` just check, in console.log, it does add, let's say I click on the Eat Dinner three times, it going to display me that yes I did click on it three times, and it will also show me the state three times, which all going to be true.

What I am doing wrong?

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Header extends React.Component
{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={showButton:false}
    }

    showButton(){
        this.setState({showButton:true})
    }

    showButtonNow()
    {
        if(this.state.showButton){
        return(
        <div>
        <h1>{this.props.task}</h1>
        <button>Edit</button>

        </div>);}
    }
    render(){
        const style = {cursor:'pointer'}
        console.log(this.props.task)
        console.log(this.state)
        return(
        <div>
        <div style={style}
        onClick={this.showButton.bind(this)}>
        {this.props.task}
        </div>
        <div>
        {this.showButtonNow()}
        </div>
        </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my original question, i wanted to display the number of click, but in reality i just want to display, that if i click on Eat Dinner three times, it should dispplay me

3. Eat Dinner

If you looking to display the Eat Dinner three times and button, just run any loop, and it will get the job done, 
I got the answer from here http://jsfiddle.net/arfyasu/h95teu70/

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Header extends React.Component
{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={showButton:false, click:0}//Added a click state to count click
    }

    showButton(){
        this.setState({showButton:true, click:this.state.click+1})// Change the value of click according to the click
    }

    showButtonNow()
    {
        if(this.state.showButton){
        return(

        <div>
        <h1>{this.state.click}{this.props.task}</h1>//Added state for click so i can display the click count
        <button>Edit</button>

        </div>);}
    }
    render(){
        const style = {cursor:'pointer'}
        console.log(this.props.task)
        console.log(this.state)
        return(
        <div>
        <div style={style}
        onClick={this.showButton.bind(this)}>
        {this.props.task}
        </div>
        <div>
        {this.showButtonNow()}
        </div>
        </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you will always only ever be showing one button because that while that function will run once for every re-render it can only ever do what you've told it to do which is display one div if the state.showButton is true.

What I would do is in your showButton method I would add the div that is in showButtonNow() to an array that's in your state, then in your render method you could iterate over that array and display all of the buttons.

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Header extends React.Component
{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={buttons:[]}
    }

    showButton(){
        let buttons = this.state.buttons;
        buttons += this.createButton();
        this.setState({buttons: buttons});
    }

    createButton()
    {
        return(
        <div>
        <h1>{this.props.task}</h1>
        <button>Edit</button>

        </div>);
    }
    render(){
        const style = {cursor:'pointer'}
        return(
        <div>
        <div style={style}
        onClick={this.showButton.bind(this)}>
        {this.props.task}
        </div>
        <div>
        {this.state.buttons}
        </div>
        </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: This line is showing me the error, `buttons += createButton();` that create button is not defined, thanks for the help

Comment: Sorry should be this.createButton()

Comment: Sorry now when i am clicking on it, it only showing me object, instead of task, I dont want to accept my answer, as this is what i originally ask, i want to accept your answer, as you are answering what i ask, if you want to get hint, just see me answer, and add a loop, i will accept your answer. Thanks for the help again